# get_tree().get_current_scene() is returning null in godot/gdscript

Tags: game-engine, godot, gdscript

I was trying to get the name of the current scene by using `get_tree().get_current_scene().get_name()` but i'm getting the error:

> Attempt to call function 'get_name' in base 'null instance' on a null
>   instance.

I found out that `get_current_scene()` was giving me `null`. This is after a change scene where the function was working as intended.
i.e.
`get_tree().get_current_scene().get_name()` in **menu.gd** returns ***menu***
`get_tree().get_current_scene().get_name()` in **game.gd** returns the ***error*** because `get_tree().get_current_scene()` is `null`

**levelManager.gd** (autoloaded singleton) [full script]

```
extends Node

const SCENE_PATH = "res://scenes/"

func change_scene(scene_name):
    deffer_call("_deffered_change_scene", scene_name)

func _deffered_change_scene(scene_name):
    var path = SCENE_PATH + scene_name + ".tscn"
    var root = get_tree().get_root()
    var current = root.get_child(root.get_child_count() - 1)
    current.free()
    var scene_resource = ResourceLoader.load(path)
    var new_scene = scene_resource.instance()
    get_tree().get_root().add_child(new_scene)
    get_tree().set_current_scene(new_scene)

func _process(_delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("close"):
        get_tree().quit()

func deffer_call(func_name, func_param):
    call_deferred(func_name, func_param)
```

--[*Shortened scripts:*]--

**menu.gd**

```
extends Node

func _ready():
    var scene_name = get_tree().get_current_scene().get_name()
    print(scene_name) # returns 'menu'

# on full version of the script, mechanism that called _change_scene here

func _change_scene():
    levelManager.change_scene("game")
```

**game.gd**

```
extends Node

#game variables declared here

func _ready():
    var scene_name = get_tree().get_current_scene().get_name()
    print(scene_name) #returns an error due to get_tree().get_current_scene() being null

# rest of the game logic code here
```

I want to know why this is the case. Is there something wrong with the way i changed scenes from **levelManager.gd**?

I resolved this issue by:
setting `var current_scene_name` in **levelManager.gd**
-- both in **menu.gd** and **game.gd** --
re-setting `current_scene_name` by calling `self.get_name()`

i.e.
**levelManager.gd**

```
var current_scene_name
```

--**menu.gd** and **game.gd** --

```
var scene_name = self.get_name()
levelManager.current_scene_name(scene_name)
```

^ This is obviously a workaround. It works but i still want to know why i'm getting different outputs after calling `get_tree()` while they practically are in the same remote location in the node.

*Screenshot*
[image: treeScreenshotBeforeAndAfterChangingScenes]

Comment: This is happening, because your _ready method is called after get_tree().get_root().add_child(new_scene), but before get_tree().set_current_scene(new_scene).

Comment: Related issue (Closed): https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/2147

Comment: Isn’t the current scene the scene that is running get_current_scene? In Game.gd you can just call get_name.